# how to narrow down dojo 1.4 javascript error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, syntax, dojo

I got a javascript error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in chrome's debugger while loading a page. we're using a customised version of dojo 1.4.x

```
n.text = code;
```

I noticed that the variable "code" had a huge amount of application code. Somewhere inside, it appears is the javascript syntax error. Since the code is huge, I don't know where exactly the problem is coming up. How do I go about narrowing down where the the problem is ?

[image: chrome's debugger view when problem occurs]

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger to get the value of the `code` variable, and copy it to the clipboard.

Paste it into a blank HTML document, or an empty JSFiddle, and run it with the console visible.  That will show you where the syntax error is.

(Even if there are missing dependencies etc., a syntax error ought to show up.)

Comment: since the code was huge, I could not copy the contents of the "code" var. That's when I posted this question!

Comment: @anjanb: Can you print it to the console (just by typing `code` into the console input field) then copy it from there?